# Slide toggle from right to left using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a menu that I would like to slide in from the right. I have the following code but some reason it isn't working. How can I correct this code?

```
jQuery("#mobile-nav-icon").click(function(){
    jQuery('#menu-main-menu').toggle(slide, right, 500);
});
```

Comment: well, what are `slide` and `right` ? Have you tried wrapping them in quotes? Also, they are not the correct parameters for `toggle`

Comment: @musefan I put them in quotes, it appears on click but wont toggle some reason. I think I am on the right track though. thanks!

Comment: have you tried [`slideToggle` function](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: @musefan yes but doesnt slide toggle only go from top to bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `jquery-ui` and use `toggle()` function to provide the direction as well

```
jQuery("#mobile-nav-icon").click(function(){
    jQuery('#menu-main-menu').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `animate()` method as such:

```
jQuery("#mobile-nav-icon").click(function(){
    jQuery('#menu-main-menu').animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

Also you can replace "jQuery" with "$", it does the same thing